# How to use FullAjaxExceptionHandler with Spring Boot error page declarations?

Tags: jsf, spring-boot, omnifaces

How can we do when use onmifaces in the case of spring boot apps?, where the error pages declaration is made at EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer class?

```
@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
    MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);

    mappings.add("eot", "application/vnd.ms-fontobject");
    mappings.add("ttf", "application/x-font-ttf");
    mappings.add("woff", "application/x-font-woff");
    mappings.add("woff2", "application/x-font-woff2");

    container.setMimeMappings(mappings);

    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/error.xhtml"));
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(FaceletException.class, "/error.xhtml"));
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(Throwable.class, "/error.xhtml"));
}
```

I have analized findErrorPageLocation and it uses WebXml that parses web.xml files.

Answer (score 1):

The Servlet API in its current version does [not](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) support programmatically defining and obtaining error pages. That's why OmniFaces had to manually parse web.xml.

OmniFaces does not and will not support Spring specific APIs. I recommend to just keep using web.xml for error page configuration so that non-Spring libraries will be able to share them.

Comment: Thanks as always @BalusC